# Is there any way to stop this htaccess redirect loop?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, mod-security

I can't figure out a way to stop this htaccess redirect from looping.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Multiviews
RewriteOptions MaxRedirects=1
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^pages/?$ page.php?p=g&id=1$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^p=g&id=1$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^page\.php$ /pages/? [r=301,nc]
```

Now it just loops until the browser says "This webpage has a redirect loop". The address bar on the browser shows the correct address at least..

Is it possible to stop it from looping?

I have tried: `RewriteOptions MaxRedirects=1` with no success.

I would like to have it so any links to /page.php?p=g&id=1 redirect to /pages/

Thanks.

Comment: What URL are you calling initially in your browser? Are those your only rules, or are there more?

Comment: I've edited my question with the full code.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 rules:

1. A -> B
2. B -> A

you've made the loop so it works as it should. You have to decide which way you want to go.

Comment: I've tried removing one and testing it, and vice versa. The loop stops but it no longer redirects to /pages/, it just stays /page.php?p=g&id=1

Comment: Please tell what you want to achieve.

Comment: I would like to have it so any links to /page.php?p=g&id=1 redirect to /pages/

Comment: @user1654748 put that statement in your question, otherwise it's not clear what you're trying to do

Answer (score 0):

You can probably just omit the first rule you had:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^p=g&id=1$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^page\.php$ /pages/? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: It's redirecting as I wanted it too with that method, but to a 404, "The requested URL xxx was not found on this server. Any suggestions?